# Python ThreadPoolExecutor on method of instance

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

In a Python project, I use ThreadPoolExecutor to multithreading my program.
I use one thread by instance of object in order to run one method. At this time, I use this syntaxe :

```
class Fqdn():
    def port_scan(self):
        # Do a TCP scan
        pass

# Used because I must submit a function with ThreadPoolExecutor
def port_scan(fqdn):
    fqdn.port_scan()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREAD_LIMIT) as executor:
    # fqdn_list is a list of Fqdn instances
    for fqdn in fqdn_list:
        executor.submit(port_scan, fqdn)
```

Do you have any idea which lets me to submit an method instance to my executor ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass the [bound method](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects), `fqdn.port_scan`:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=THREAD_LIMIT) as executor:
    # fqdn_list is a list of Fqdn instances
    for fqdn in fqdn_list:
        executor.submit(fqdn.port_scan)
```